# Solving problems through answering my own question

Tags: support, self-answer

I recently found some solution to some integral, I want to share some methods that may help people who are new to calculus. Can I make my thread kind of like a tutorial, or is that off-topic or will it be closed by the moderators?

For example:
Title: How to solve the integral of $x^2$.
Answer: A tutorial about the power rule $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ (Not that basic but I don't want to type the full thing)

Is this type of thing allowed and if not, what can I do with the "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" checkbox?

Comment: Sorry for being circumspect, but the first thing to do is make sure that the post you intend to create is not a duplicate. This may not be the case in general, but looking at your example, I feel like there is probably some duplicate lying around explaining the power rule well.

Comment: Ok so even after searching no duplicates, if I do it this way, will it be closed for "off-topic"? The actual thing im thinking about writing is about normal distributions of that sorts.

Comment: Without being too picky about duplication : If I trust you when you say you are not posting a duplicate, then what I'd like to see is your post coming out. I don't expect it to be closed as off-topic, if your question follows the guidelines. There is always one option if you're a little concerned : let me know what question you have, or go over [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback) to the constructive feedback chatroom if you have trouble *after* posting your question. Call me there, and we can discuss issues. Sometimes, these surface only after posting.

Comment: Its about taking the integral of the normal distribution function using 2 different methods.

Comment: Also see [What is SE etiquette when answering your own question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20972/what-is-se-etiquette-when-answering-your-own-question?rq=1)